# Retrieve JSON from CSV using python in desired format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, automation, csvtojson

Many thanks in advance, I have been keen on collecting some insights on getting the below output from its corresponding input. Would like to see the table getting converted to a desirable format via using a python script as I have to work with a huge CSV at a later stage. Any inputs are highly appreciated.

**Input CSV:**

| reference | mcc | value | currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 5300 | 134.09 | USD |
| 10001 | 5651 | 128.95 | USD |
| 10002 | 5912 | 104.71 | USD |

**Used python code:**

```
from csv import DictReader
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint
import json

with open('Test_bulk_transactions_data.csv') as csvfile:
    r = DictReader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r]

    group = []
    uniquekeys = []

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['reference'], r['mcc'])):
        group.append({
            "reference": k[0],
            "mcc": k[1],
            "amount": [{k:v for k, v in d.items() if k not in ['reference','mcc']} for d in list(g)]})
        uniquekeys.append(k)

print(json.dumps(group, indent = 3) + '}')
```

**Current Output:**

```
  {
   "reference": "10000",
   "mcc": "5300",
   "amount": [
    {
     "value": "134.09",
     "currency": "USD"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "reference": "10001",
   "mcc": "5651",
   "amount": [
    {
     "value": "128.95",
     "currency": "USD"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "reference": "10002",
   "mcc": "5912",
   "amount": [ 
    {
     "value": "104.71",
     "currency": "USD"
    }
   ]
  }
```

**Desired Output JSON:**

```
  {
   "reference": "10000",
   "mcc": "5300",
   "amount": {
     "value": 134.09,
     "currency": "USD"
    }
  },
  {
   "reference": "10001",
   "mcc": "5651",
   "amount": {
     "value": 128.95,
     "currency": "USD"
    }
  },
  {
   "reference": "10002",
   "mcc": "5912",
   "amount": {
     "value": 104.71,
     "currency": "USD"
    }
  }
```

- **Important Note**:
  Amount shouldn't fall into [] and that the value should stand as a numeric output and not strings.

Comment: Please, check [ask]. What have you tried so far and what specific problem you are not able to solve? Do you have problem open/read/parse csv, file, create desired data structure, dump it to JSON?

Comment: I've edited the question, hopefully now it works ? @buran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

csv_filepath =  "/home/mhs/test.csv"
 
output = []


with open(csv_filepath) as cd:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(cd)
    for r in csvReader:
        r["amount"] = {"value": float(r.pop("value")), "currency": r.pop("currency")}
        output.append(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without relying on imported modules, you could just do this:

```
J = []

with open('input.csv') as csv:
    cols = next(csv).split()
    assert len(cols) == 4
    for row in csv:
        t = row.split()
        if len(t) == 4:
            J.append({cols[0]: t[0], cols[1]: t[1], "amount": {cols[2]: float(t[2]), cols[3]: t[3]}})


print(J)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it's giving an error: 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: Your input file may contain empty lines. I'll edit the code to add a sanity check. Also, in the absence of information to the contrary, this code assumes that the columns are whitespace delimited

Comment: Hi again, I tried the updated code and now it is giving "AssertionError: " :)

Comment: That's because the first line in your csv file does not contain 4 whitespace delimited tokens. If you could show what your csv file actually looks like you'd be a whole lot better off

Comment: Sure, I'll try to find a fix, thanks for many help :)

Comment: Some history may help you. CSV stands for Comma-Separated Values. However, over time this has become a generic term for files containing tokens (values) separated by anything that's unambiguous in the context of the tokens themselves. So, a CSV might use comma, whitespace, pipe, colon, semi-colon, exclamation mark - just anything. If your file is using commas you just need to change the *split()* to *split(',')* although you may need to trim (strip) any text values to remove redundant whitespace

Comment: Thanks for the kind explanation and sharing insights :) 
It has been really helpful to understand handling CSVs, much appreciated..!